# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: plugins, craft-pro

I am having a syntax error on my craftCMS website. Hoping someone could help me.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home16/puresoci/public_html/dev/craft/plugins/charge/ChargePlugin.php on line 14

Here's the line that it is referring to

```
  craft()->templates->hook('charge.prepCpTemplate', [$this, 'prepCpTemplate']);
```

Here's the whole function

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->charge_license->ping();

    if (craft()->request->isCpRequest()) {
        $this->includeCpResources();
        craft()->templates->hook('charge.prepCpTemplate', [$this, 'prepCpTemplate']);
        craft()->templates->hook('charge.prepCpSettingsTemplate', [$this, 'prepCpSettingsTemplate']);
    }
}
```

But I am a beginner on using PHP and I dont know how should I update this. I am using PHP 5.6 right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Charge plugin requires a minimum of **PHP 5.4**.

The brackets notation for arrays (which is what Charge uses) was added in 5.4.

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Contact your hosting provider to find out how to upgrade.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.6 it works fine yesterday but when I open it today I got that error.

Comment: Your post explicitly says you found a message stating "You are using PHP 5.3." I'd recommend you check again.

Comment: Sorry about that the quote below 'You are using PHP 5.3. The Array Initialization Construct: [] will not work. Instead, use this approach:' is what I just researched in the internet. I am using PHP 5.6 right now.

Comment: What I'm saying is, I don't think you are. Go to the `/admin/utils/phpinfo` page of your site, and see what it says there. That will tell you which version Craft itself is seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if you can, I'd upgrade your hosting to use PHP 7. It's about 2x as fast as 5.x, and it's much more modern. PHP 5.3 isn't even supported anymore.

Comment: Sorry about that the quote below 'You are using PHP 5.3. The Array Initialization Construct: [] will not work. Instead, use this approach:' is what I just researched in the internet. I am using PHP 5.6

Comment: I updated my question so everyone will not get confused.